# How to transfer/stream data to multiple USB device in parallel

Tags: windows, usb, windows-8.1, usb-storage

I am trying to transfer and/or stream data to multiple USB devices and/or storage simultaneously. For example, if I have a USB hub with 12 USB sockets connecting to 12 USB displays, I like all 12 displays to display the same data simultaneously. Or, if I want to transfer files to 12 USB storage, I like to do in one drag-and-drop and all 12 storages will be copied simultaneously.

I am thinking there is a way to "mask" (not sure if that's the right word) the 12 USB port as one USB port and the data can be streamed in parallel across all USB ports. Or, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Fully simultaneous: Nope.

Multiplexed: (hub gets data from PC, send data to port 1), (hub gets data from PC, send data to port 2), (hub gets data from PC, send data to port 3): Yes.

At this point the feed from the PC to the hub might well become the bottleneck.

What you probably want is one USB controller per channel, which might mean on add-in card per channel.